# service activator acting as outbound gateway for invoking bean method

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and was going through the definition of service activator. The definition says that it is used to `call a method and wrap the result in the response message.` The definition also tells that it is a `outbound gateway for invoking the bean method.` I am not clear on the second statement. As I understand outbound gateway is to send the request from the application to external application and get the response back into the application. So, if a bean is invoked, it is invoked within the application and hence it should be inbound gateway right. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of integration - with external systems using various protocols, and with legacy java code using method invocation.

Within that, there are one-way integrations (provided by channel adapters) and two-way integration (request/response, provided by gateways). In each case, the integration can be inbound to the message flow, or outbound from it.

The `<int: .../>` namespace provides inbound and outbound channel adapters for invoking legacy code from the messaging flow, in the latter case (outbound) the method return type must be `null`. You could also invoke the same method with a service activator, but the channel adapter is preferred because it's clear it's a one-way integration.

On the inbound side, the messaging gateway (`<int:gateway/>`) is provided to allow legacy java code interact with the messaging flow ("call" it) without any specific dependencies.

There is no `<int:outbound-gateway/>` for invoking a method because the service activator provides that functionality.

If you can point us to the documentation that caused the confusion, we can try to improve it; please open a [documentation JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have created a Jira ticket.

Comment: Please, also find my explanation in the target JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4073. I'm not sure that we have to change anything else. There is need to start studying from the EIP as a theory IMHO...